# How do I find the hypothesis based on a training set without implementing linear regression?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, self-study

So I was going through Andrew Ng's ML course and I encountered this question.

---

[image: Andrew Ng ML course quiz question]

As far as I know, the purpose of the cost function is to minimize the difference between $h(x^i) - y^i$. Since I can't assume that the output $y$ will be exactly on the regression line, I can't set $h(x^i) - y^i = 0$ to solve for $\theta_0$ and $\theta_1$. As mentioned in the question:

> You should be able to select the right answer without actually
>   implementing linear regression

Is it possible to obtain a solution to this question without plotting the graph? If so, how do I approach it?

Comment: Plot the points in a scatter plot and see if you cant rule out three alternatives based on that. My guess is option two ....ask yourself what does $\theta_1$ and $\theta_0$ with respect to the line?

Comment: Is it possible to do it without plotting?

Comment: Do you think $\theta_1$ is positive or negative?

Comment: I assume it's positive due to the negative correlation. As $x$ increases, Y decreases. But even so, I can't be sure whether $\theta_0$ would be either $-1780.0$ or $-569.6$.

Comment: For which of these functions $y=2-2x$ and $y=2+2x$ does $y$ decrease when $x$ increase and what is $\theta_1$ in those two instances?

Comment: $y = 2 - 2x$ has a negative slope, therefore $y$ decreases when $x$ increases. So does that mean that the choices given is focused on the slope, but not the value itself?

Comment: No but it means that if x increases and y then decrease ... then the association is negative, the slope of the line you plot is negative, which is $\theta_1$. Not positive as you said, i think you might have to brush up the basics of linear functions.

Comment: Noted. But how do I pick between the 3rd and 4th answer without performing linear regression? For instance, if $\theta_0 = -1780.0$, that means that when $x = 0$, $y = -1780.0$. How do I know that the line is the best fitting line in that case? My idea is to take the first and last training example and plug them into $h(x)$, and compare the squared error, and take the lowest one. Is this approach correct? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would argue ....

First observe that as $x$ increase $y$ decrease hence the slope of the regression line measured by $\theta_1$ must be negative ruling out option 3 and 4.

In both of the first two options the slope is the same $\theta_1 = -530.9$ hence the specific value of $\theta_1$ can therefore be assumed to be $-530.9$.

Putting this knowledge to use I observe that at $x=1$ the value for $y=-890$. If the line  good approximation then $\theta_0 + \theta_1 x$ should be fairly close to this value when $x=1$ implying that

$-890 \approx \theta_0 - 530.9$

which implies that

$\theta_0 \approx 530.9 - 890 =  -359.1$

since the candidates for $\theta_0$ are as given in option 1 and 2 I choose option 2 because this is the option where $\theta_0$ is closest to $-359.1$.

Do I know with **certainty** that this is the correct guess? NO, surely my guess is based solely on information from the point $x=1,y=-890$. So another procedure would be to plot the points and draw best line by hand while trying to approximate the slope $-530.9$ and then simply read of the value at $x=0$ this would be an easy way of using info on all points.

Otherwise you can try with $x=2$ where $y=-1411$ so if the line is close to actual observation then

$$-1411 \approx \theta_0 - 530.9 * 2$$ such that

$$2*530.9-1411 =  -349.2 \approx \theta_0 $$

and off course you can do this for all points ...

And this process is just error minimization so yes you could also calculate errors as you suggest and square and add them for a number of points and then select based on that ... but off course in the end using all points this would be linear regression and the idea was not to perform linear regression ...

Comment: Well explained with clear understanding! Thank you!